# VSCode: Sort imports vs. Organize Imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I enter `option` + `shift` + `o` on my Mac in a Python file in VSCode, I am given two options - "Sort imports" and "Organize Imports". They both organize the inputs nicely but in a different way, so I can keep flipping back and forth between the two of them. Why are there two different commands for this and is one preferred (i.e. more PEP8 compliant) than the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two because the Python extension created the [`Sort Imports` command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_sort-imports) before VS Code introduced the [`Organize Imports` command](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_run-code-actions-on-save). So the `Sort Imports` command is the more "official" one for now.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9288), though, to transition over to `Organize Imports` at some point. Feel free to  the issue if you would like to help bump its priority.